# req.body reveals password when I console.log it in Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am working with NodeJs in the backend and I console.log(req.body) from a form which is to collect user's username and password.

I discover that it reveals the username and password from that form.

Does this mean my code is vulnerable? Or is that how it ought to be?

Though the user's password is hashed and stored in a database.

Comment: The password to compare against is hopefully hashed in the database, but the password the user types in is generally not hashed for comparison until sent to the server. That’s what’s in `req.body`.  Just be careful about logging potentially sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `req.body` will contain any and all data passed to it, including the password.

Just don't send it to the console in your production environment.

Instead you use those values to validate the user, save in a DB or do whatever other logic you need to do.

If `req.body` didn't have the password then how would you be able to validate the user trying to log in?

Answer (score 1):

Any form's data that you are sending to the server will necessarily be visible at the server.  This is normal.  This is how the client sends data to the server.

It is only insecure if you are running it over http (instead of https) such that connection points in the middle could see the password or such that your server's DNS could be hijaacked or if you do something insecure with it on the server (store it improperly, log it to log files, etc...).

If you are running over properly secured https and you hash the password on the server and store only a hash and have proper security measures for the security of your database, then you would be doing what most sites do.

Answer (score 0):

If the printing is necessary in your code, you can use a environment flag, commonly I set an attribute in config.js, for example, "devMode":true, then I use this attribute for printing, for example:

const { devMode } = require('./config.js');
...

if(devMode) console.log('Hello World');

when You make a deploy for production, You only need to change devMode to false